# How to import files Generated by the SAS Excelxp Tagset (v1.130) in SAS?

Tags: xml, excel, sas

I have a bunch of files Generated by the SAS Excelxp Tagset .v1.130. These are XML files saved with an XLS extension. I assume there is a way to read them back into SAS, as they were generated by a ODS destination as far as I can tell but I tried a libname XML statement without success and I can't find information online beside a SAS2XML macro that is sold for 10000$.

Does anybody know a way to read them in?

Comment: Out of curiousity where's the SAS2XML macro for $10,000. I'm actually not sure it can read the file back in, especially if there's been a lot of custom formatting applied. If I had to do this, I would first convert to xls or xlsx and read from that file. There's a 'free' VB script that does the conversion on SAS's website.

Comment: Have you tried proc import?   Technically these are a valid (but obsolete) Excel file format, but I don't know if the SAS engine will recognize them.

Comment: The XML2SAS macro is on sale here: http://www.try2.info/xml2sas.htm, it seems.

Comment: @david25272 proc import would fail as it can't read the XML files. See below for a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to _data_null_ for finding the answer on sas knowledge base:

http://support.sas.com/kb/43/496.html

you would need the map for the XML tagset that was used to format the output, in my case the default excelXP tagset was enough.